# Covering Up Window With Shower Wall

Tags: shower

I need to replace a bathroom window which has cracked. At the same time, I'm replacing a jacuzzi tub with a walk-in shower and plan to cover the bathroom window with backerboard and tile. I'd like to ensure the new window doesn't crack due to the heat which will now be trapped. The window installer assures me it will be fine since he's using Low-E glass. Anything else I need to add between the glass the the backerboard (insulation? tint?)? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just remove the window if you will cover it up?

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately, my house is brick and the window is prominently visible. I don't know what to "fill" the space with besides another window where it wouldn't look ugly/stupid.

Comment: I think it may look ugly from outside. Easy solution is remove window, place brick in the opening, mortared of course, insulate from inside then cover. If you cover it, it will, at some point, mold from condensation. Or, tile around it and leave it as is and usable. If it opens, then it will be good for ventilation.